# Easiest Way to Assign Array to Individual Objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

In python you can do:

```
goat, cabbage, wolf, farmer = puzzle.passengers
```

where array is a list of some type.

Is there a quick way to do the samething in typescript?

I tried:

```
var goat: Passenger, cabbage: Passenger, wolf: Passenger, farmer: Passenger = puzzle.passengers
```

but I get the following error

> Type Passenger[] is not assignable to type Passenger
>
> Property type is missing in type Passenger[]

in reference to the declaration of the `farmer` variable

Comment: Array destructuring assignment?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware of the correct terminology

Comment: No worries, your question is valid, I don't understand the downvotes. Though I think widening your search to not just TypeScript and searching 'unpacking variables in javascript' could've given faster results.